# Android/Java - How pass a global variable value from main activity to a runnable class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, global-variables, runnable

I have a global variable in my main activity called "pinNumberConverted". I need to get the value of this variable in another class of type runnable (inside there is a server socket). How can i do it?
This is the main activity:

```
public class AndroidServer2 extends Activity {

  Random pin_generator = new Random();
  public int pin_number = pin_generator.nextInt(9000-1000 +1) +1000; //generate a random code for the first connection with the kiosk
  public String pinNumberConverted = String.valueOf(pin_number);
  Thread fst = new Thread(new MyServer()); //declaration of a new thread

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_server2);
    initialize();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Utilities utilities = new Utilities();
    utilities.connectionInfo(this, wiFi, wifiInfo, ipAddress, wirelessName, pin, ipAddressConversion, serverIp, pin_number);
    if (fst.isAlive() == false){
        fst.start();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the runnable class:

```
public class MyServer implements Runnable{

    //Need to pass the information taken from connection info method in Utilities.java
    public Handler handler = new Handler();
    public ServerSocket serverSocket;
    MyServerMethods myServerMethods = new MyServerMethods();
    AndroidServer2 androidServer2 = new AndroidServer2(); //this doesn't work and give error in runtime

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
          ServerSocket parent = new ServerSocket(); //create a new socket
          parent.setReuseAddress(true);
          parent.bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverPort)); //bind the server port and reuse it if necessary
            if ( serverIp != null){
                Log.i("Status","READY");
                while (true){
                    Socket client = parent.accept(); //accept the incoming connection
            //Here i need to take the value of the global variable from the main activity               
               } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: One way is to pass a reference to your activity in your Runnable's contructor and then just call a getter on it.

Comment: Thanks Ken. How can i do it? Is there a tutorial or something to read?

Comment: add constructor: `public MyServer(string pin){ fieldInMyServerPin = pin; }`

Comment: It is giving syntax error now. It required also that i remove the Override over the run method and request to create a new one with the Override.

Comment: If you don't need to access it again go with @Selvin's approach.

Comment: It is giving me these errors with @Selvin approach.

Comment: you need to declare `String fieldInMyServerPin;` in `MyServer` class and then change `new Thread(new MyServer())` to `new Thread(new MyServer(pinNumberConverted))` then you can use this field (`fieldInMyServerPin`) in other places in `MyServer` class

Comment: Ok i have modified the new Thread(new MyServer(pinNumberConverted)) and added the variable String fieldInMyServerPin; in the runnable class. Now Eclipse is giving me this error in the main activity "The constructor MyServer(String) is undefined".